# Efficient way to run a function over the columns of a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

I want to run a function over the columns of a Pandas Dataframe. 
Corpus is a pd.Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

corpus = pd.DataFrame([[3,1,1,1,1,60],[2,2,0,2,0,20], [0,2,1,1,0,0], [0,0,2,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0,1,0]],index=["stark","groß","schwach","klein", "dick"],columns=["d1", "d2", "d3","d4","d5","d6"])
```

And I have query. Query is a Pandas Series.

```
query = pd.Series([1,1,0,0,0], index=["stark","groß","schwach","klein", "dick"])
```

Now I want to run the cosine function over every column in corpus and the query.

```
for column in corpus:
print("Similarity of Documents", column," and query: \n" ,1-cosine(query, corpus[column]))
```

Is there a better way to run the cosine fuction over the columns? Maybe some method that gets the columns and runs the function over every column. I want to avoid the for Loop.

Comment: the cosine function is just imported from scipy.spatial.distance 

scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(u, v)

u and v are arrays. (cosine computes the distance between two 1-D Arrays. )

Comment: Thank u, you're right. I edited my question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist's`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) `'cosine'` functionality for a vectorized soliution, like so -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

out = 1-cdist(query.values[None], corpus.values.T, 'cosine')
```

Sample run -

```
In [192]: corpus
Out[192]: 
         d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  d6
stark     3   1   1   1   1  60
groß      2   2   0   2   0  20
schwach   0   2   1   1   0   0
klein     0   0   2   1   0   1
dick      0   0   0   0   1   0

In [193]: query
Out[193]: 
stark      1
groß       1
schwach    0
klein      0
dick       0
dtype: int64

In [194]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

In [195]: for column in corpus:
     ...:     print(1-cosine(query, corpus[column]))
     ...:     
0.980580675691
0.707106781187
0.288675134595
0.801783725737
0.5
0.89431540856

In [196]: 1-cdist(query.values[None], corpus.values.T, 'cosine')
Out[196]: array([[ 0.98058,  0.70711,  0.28868,  0.80178,  0.5    ,  0.89432]])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [225]: corpus = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,10000))

In [226]: query = pd.Series(np.random.rand(100))

# @C.Square's apply based soln
In [227]: %timeit corpus.apply(lambda x:1-cosine(query, x), axis=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 352 ms per loop

 # Proposed in this post using cdist()
In [228]: %timeit 1-cdist(query.values[None], corpus.values.T, 'cosine')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the definition of `cosine` and implement yourself

**`pandas`**

```
corpus.T.dot(query) / (corpus ** 2).sum() ** .5 / (query ** 2).sum() ** .5

d1    0.980581
d2    0.707107
d3    0.288675
d4    0.801784
d5    0.500000
d6    0.894315
dtype: float64
```

---

**`numpy`**

```
c = corpus.values
q = query.values

r = c.T.dot(q) / (c ** 2).sum(0) ** .5 / (q ** 2).sum() ** .5

pd.Series(r, corpus.columns)

d1    0.980581
d2    0.707107
d3    0.288675
d4    0.801784
d5    0.500000
d6    0.894315
dtype: float64
```

**with @Divakar's suggestion**
*`np.einsum`*

```
c = corpus.values
q = query.values

r = (
        np.einsum('ji,j->i', c, q) /
        np.einsum('ij,ij->j', c, c) ** .5 /
        np.einsum('i,i', q, q) ** .5
    )

pd.Series(r, corpus.columns)

d1    0.980581
d2    0.707107
d3    0.288675
d4    0.801784
d5    0.500000
d6    0.894315
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I see `einsum` there for `(c ** 2).sum(0)` and the other one!

Answer (score 0):

`apply`-ing functions is a neat, readable and a quick way for such a job:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

corpus = pd.DataFrame([[3,1,1,1,1,60],[2,2,0,2,0,20], [0,2,1,1,0,0], [0,0,2,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0,1,0]], index=["stark","groß","schwach","klein", "dick"], columns=["d1", "d2", "d3","d4","d5","d6"])
query = pd.Series([1,1,0,0,0], index=["stark","groß","schwach","klein", "dick"])

corpus.apply(lambda x:1-cosine(query, x),  # Apply your function
             axis=0)                       # For each column

# d1    0.980581
# d2    0.707107
# d3    0.288675
# d4    0.801784
# d5    0.500000
# d6    0.894315
# dtype: float64
```